# vault helm chart: Enable prometheus metrics

Tags: hashicorp-vault

How does one enable [prometheus metric collection](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/telemetry/#prometheus) in Hashicorp Vault when deployed via the [helm chart](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm)?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You need to add things like 'telemetry' (and other configuration stanzas) to the `server.ha.config` data structure in your values.yaml. This will push changes to vault's configmap. You then bounce all vault nodes and you're good-to-go!

Comment: can you be specific add an example e.g. values.yaml and helm install command